# Pandas: Multiple rolling periods

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I would like to get multiple rolling period means and std for several columns simultaneously.

This is the code I am using for rolling(5):

```
def add_mean_std_cols(df):
    res = df.rolling(5).agg(['mean','std'])

    res.columns = res.columns.map('_'.join)

    cols = np.concatenate(list(zip(df.columns, res.columns[0::2], res.columns[1::2])))

    final = res.join(df).loc[:, cols]
    return final
```

I would like to the get rolling (5), (15), (30), (45) periods on the same operation.

I thought about iterating over periods but do not know how to avoid getting the rolling mean/std of the rolling mean/std...

Comment: So you want the result to be like the original dataframe with a mean and standard deviation for each column and for each period?  I.e. if you had 3 original columns, your new frame will be 3 x 2 x 4 = 24 columns?  Do you think a a multiindex dataframe or a dict of dataframes would make sense?

Comment: @BradSolomon, your number is correct. The simpler the better. The dataframe will feed a csv file where I will store the data for later retrieval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a DataFrame with a MultiIndex as its columns.  There's no way around using a loop here to iterate over your windows. The resulting form will be something that's easy to index and easy to read with `pd.read_csv`.  Initialize an empty DataFrame with `np.empty` of the appropriate shape and use `.loc` to assign its values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(123)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3)).add_prefix('col')

windows = [5, 15, 30, 45]
stats = ['mean', 'std']
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([windows, df.columns, stats], 
                                  names=['window', 'feature', 'metric'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((df.shape[0], len(cols))), columns=cols,
                   index=df.index)

for window in windows:
    df2.loc[:, window] = df.rolling(window=window).agg(stats).values
```

Now you have a result `df2` that has the same index as your original object.  It has 3 column levels: the first is the window, the second is the columns from your original frame, and the third is the statistic.

```
print(df2.shape)
(100, 24)
```

This makes it easy to check values for a specific rolling window:

```
print(df2[5])  # Rolling window = 5
feature     col0              col1              col2         
metric      mean      std     mean      std     mean      std
0            NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
1            NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2            NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
3            NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
4       -0.87879  1.45348 -0.26559  0.71236  0.53233  0.89430
..           ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
95      -0.44231  1.02552 -1.22138  0.45140 -0.36440  0.95324
96      -0.58638  1.10246 -0.90165  0.79723 -0.44543  1.00166
97      -0.70564  0.85711 -0.42644  1.07174 -0.44766  1.00284
98      -0.95702  1.01302 -0.03705  1.05066  0.16437  1.32341
99      -0.57026  1.10978  0.08730  1.02438  0.39930  1.31240

print(df2[5]['col0'])  # Rolling window = 5, stats of col0 only
metric     mean      std
0           NaN      NaN
1           NaN      NaN
2           NaN      NaN
3           NaN      NaN
4      -0.87879  1.45348
..          ...      ...
95     -0.44231  1.02552
96     -0.58638  1.10246
97     -0.70564  0.85711
98     -0.95702  1.01302
99     -0.57026  1.10978

print(df2.loc[:, (5, slice(None), 'mean')]) # Rolling window = 5,
                                            # means of each column
period         5                  
feature     col0     col1     col2
metric      mean     mean     mean
0            NaN      NaN      NaN
1            NaN      NaN      NaN
2            NaN      NaN      NaN
3            NaN      NaN      NaN
4       -0.87879 -0.26559  0.53233
..           ...      ...      ...
95      -0.44231 -1.22138 -0.36440
96      -0.58638 -0.90165 -0.44543
97      -0.70564 -0.42644 -0.44766
98      -0.95702 -0.03705  0.16437
99      -0.57026  0.08730  0.39930
```

And lastly to make a single-indexed DataFrame, here's some kludgy use of `itertools`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3)).add_prefix('col')

import itertools

means = [col + '_mean' for col in df.columns]
stds = [col + '_std' for col in df.columns]
iters = [iter(means), iter(stds)]
iters = list(it.__next__() for it in itertools.cycle(iters))
iters = list(itertools.product(iters, [str(win) for win in windows]))
iters = ['_'.join(it) for it in iters]

df2 = [df.rolling(window=window).agg(stats).values for window in windows]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df2, axis=1), columns=iters,
                   index=df.index)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution !! My concern is that I am going to use this data for machine learning so I am going to be adding more features. I am not sure if this structure could complicate data handling.

Comment: For simplicity I would prefer a plain dataframe...although I image it is not easy to achieve...thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate output of multiple rolling aggregations:

```
windows = (5, 15, 30, 45)
rolling_dfs = (df.rolling(i)                                    # 1. Create window
                 .agg(['mean', 'std'])                          # 1. Aggregate
                 .rename_axis({col: '{0}_{1:d}'.format(col, i)
                               for col in df.columns}, axis=1)  # 2. Rename columns
               for i in windows)                                # For each window

pd.concat((df, *rolling_dfs), axis=1)                           # 3. Concatenate dataframes
```

This is not pretty but should do what you're looking for from what I understand.

What it does:

1. creates a generator `rolling_dfs` with the aggregated dataframes for each rolling window size.
2. renames all columns so you can know which rolling window size it refers to.
3. concatenates the original `df` with the rolling windows.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I get TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object.

Comment: This code is working on my side with a df of floats. You should show a sample of your specific df of interest for further investigation.

Comment: @FabienP Hi, have you find any method chaining work-around ?:)