# Finding an faster code to implement mean() function on many columns for different windows of rolling function

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

can someone suggest a better shorter method to apply the same given below code. 
the given code were implemented for four columns, with different window of rolling function.
And now I want to implement the same with 10 columns and then merge them later.
plsss help!

So I had data with columns like Sr.No., Company Name, pe, price_bv, mpcap_ns and ev_ebidta.
i would be grateful if someone helps me.

```
 df2 = df1.groupby(level=0)['pe'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=3650).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_pe_10_yrs')

df222 = df1.groupby(level=0)['pe'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=3650).std()).reset_index(name='Stdev_pe_10_yrs')

df3 = df1.groupby(level=0)['price_bv'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=3650).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_price_bv_10_yrs')

df333 = df1.groupby(level=0)['price_bv'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=3650).std()).reset_index(name='Stdev_price_bv_10_yrs')
#print(df333)

df4 = df1.groupby(level=0)['mcap_ns'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=3650).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_mcap_ns_10_yrs')
#print(df4)

df444 = df1.groupby(level=0)['mcap_ns'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=3650).std()).reset_index(name='Stdev_mcap_ns_10_yrs')
#print(df444)

df5 = df1.groupby(level=0)['ev_ebidta'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=3650).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_ev_ebidta_10_yrs')
#print(df5)

df555 = df1.groupby(level=0)['ev_ebidta'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=3650).std()).reset_index(name='Stdev_ev_ebidta_10_yrs')
#print(df555)

df6 = df1.groupby(level=0)['pe'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=10).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_pe_10_days')
#print(df6)

df7 = df1.groupby(level=0)['pe'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=20).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_pe_20_days')
#print(df7)

df8 = df1.groupby(level=0)['pe'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=30).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_pe_30_days')
#print(df8)

df9 = df1.groupby(level=0)['pe'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=40).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_pe_40_days')
#print(df9)

df10 = df1.groupby(level=0)['pe'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=50).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_pe_50_days')
#print(df10)

df14 = df1.groupby(level=0)['price_bv'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=10).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_price_bv_10_days')
#print(df14)

df15 = df1.groupby(level=0)['price_bv'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=20).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_price_bv_20_days')

df16 = df1.groupby(level=0)['price_bv'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=30).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_price_bv_30_days')

df17 = df1.groupby(level=0)['price_bv'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=40).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_price_bv_40_days')

df18 = df1.groupby(level=0)['price_bv'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=50).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_price_bv_50_days')

df22 = df1.groupby(level=0)['mcap_ns'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=10).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_mcap_ns_10_days')

df23 = df1.groupby(level=0)['mcap_ns'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=20).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_mcap_ns_20_days')

df24 = df1.groupby(level=0)['mcap_ns'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=30).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_mcap_ns_30_days')

df25 = df1.groupby(level=0)['mcap_ns'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=40).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_mcap_ns_40_days')

df26 = df1.groupby(level=0)['mcap_ns'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=50).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_mcap_ns_50_days')

df30 = df1.groupby(level=0)['ev_ebidta'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=10).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_ev_ebidta_10_days')
#print(df30)

df31 = df1.groupby(level=0)['ev_ebidta'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=20).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_ev_ebidta_20_days')
#print(df31)

df32 = df1.groupby(level=0)['ev_ebidta'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=30).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_ev_ebidta_30_days')
#print(df32)

df33 = df1.groupby(level=0)['ev_ebidta'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=40).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_ev_ebidta_40_days')
#print(df33)

df34 = df1.groupby(level=0)['ev_ebidta'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1,window=50).mean()).reset_index(name='Average_ev_ebidta_50_days')
#print(df34)
```

Edit: thx for the code Parfait. 
the given code is running for the past 3 hours now and hasn't given me any output yet, what should I do? plss help

Comment: You have to loop through the different window sizes to get what you want. Here is a similar question and check the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144352/pandas-multiple-rolling-periods

Comment: Current pandas does not support *name* argument in [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). However, it is supported in [`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a defined function by replacing individual column and lambda calls with `groupby().apply()`. Within the function, iterate across all combinations of column, window, and aggregation parameters with `itertools.product`. Below assumes you use Python 3.6+ that support F-strings, otherwise replace with `str.format`:

```
from itertools import product
...

def calc_rolling(grp):
    cols = ['pe', 'price_bv', 'mcap_ns', 'ev_ebidta']

    for col, agg in product(cols, ['mean', 'std']):
        t = {'mean': 'Average', 'std': 'Stdev'}    
        grp[f"{t[agg]}_{col}_10_yrs"] = grp[col].shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=3650).apply(agg)

    for col, w in product(cols, [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]):
        grp[f"Average_{col}_{w}_days"] = grp[col].shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=w).mean()

    return grp

# BUILD DATA FRAME OF 34 COLUMNS
windows_df = df1.groupby(level=0).apply(calc_rolling)
```

Output

```
print(windows_df.columns)
# Index(['Sr.No.', 'Company Name', 'pe', 'price_bv', 'mcap_ns', 'ev_ebidta',
#        'Average_pe_10_yrs', 'Stdev_pe_10_yrs', 'Average_price_bv_10_yrs',
#        'Stdev_price_bv_10_yrs', 'Average_mcap_ns_10_yrs',
#        'Stdev_mcap_ns_10_yrs', 'Average_ev_ebidta_10_yrs',
#        'Stdev_ev_ebidta_10_yrs', 'Average_pe_10_days', 'Average_pe_20_days',
#        'Average_pe_30_days', 'Average_pe_40_days', 'Average_pe_50_days',
#        'Average_price_bv_10_days', 'Average_price_bv_20_days',
#        'Average_price_bv_30_days', 'Average_price_bv_40_days',
#        'Average_price_bv_50_days', 'Average_mcap_ns_10_days',
#        'Average_mcap_ns_20_days', 'Average_mcap_ns_30_days',
#        'Average_mcap_ns_40_days', 'Average_mcap_ns_50_days',
#        'Average_ev_ebidta_10_days', 'Average_ev_ebidta_20_days',
#        'Average_ev_ebidta_30_days', 'Average_ev_ebidta_40_days',
#        'Average_ev_ebidta_50_days'],
#       dtype='object')
```

Alternatively, directly assign columns without `groupby().apply()`:

```
cols = ['pe', 'price_bv', 'mcap_ns', 'ev_ebidta']

for col, agg in product(cols, ['mean', 'std']):
    t = {'mean': 'Average', 'std': 'Stdev'}
    df1[f"{t[agg]}_{col}_10_yrs"] = df1[col].groupby(level=0).shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=3650).apply(agg)

for col, w in product(cols, [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]):
    df1[f"Average_{col}_{w}_days"] = df1[col].groupby(level=0).shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=w).mean()

print(df1.columns)
```

Comment: hello, tysm for the code. idk why but the code keeps running for more than two hours now. is there a faster code? or is there any mistake? i asked my mentor, he told me to use transform function instead of apply function since it is faster, is that true? pls help

Comment: Try directly assigning columns without `groupby().apply()`. See extended answer at bottom. If still long running, it may simply be data size and amount of rolling window aggregations.